# How to center an element horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css, layout, alignment, centering

I am trying to center my tabs content vertically, but when I add the CSS style `display:inline-flex`, the horizontal text-align disappears.

How can I make both text alignments x and y for each of my tabs?

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
#leftFrame {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 60%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#leftFrame #tabs {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 25%;
}
#leftFrame #tabs div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: static;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id=leftFrame>
  <div id=tabs>
    <div>first</div>
    <div>second</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this tutorial for aligning a div horizontally and vertically using CSS: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-center-a-div-horizontally-and-vertically-using-css/

Answer (score 874, accepted):

#### CSS flexbox / grid method:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/yeaqrh48/) / [**Full Screen Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yeaqrh48/show)

In [supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), set the `display` of the targeted element to `flex` and use `align-items: center` for vertical centering and `justify-content: center` for horizontal centering. Remember the parent container will also need height (in this case, 100%).

```css
html, body, .container {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <span>I'm vertically/horizontally centered!</span>
</div>
```

---

#### `transform` `translateX`/`translateY` method:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/47x60k4w/) / [**Full Screen Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/47x60k4w/show)

In [supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) (most of them), you can use `top: 50%`/`left: 50%` in combination with  `translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)` to dynamically vertically/horizontally center the element.

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span>I'm vertically/horizontally centered!</span>
</div>
```

---

#### `table-cell`/`vertical-align: middle` method:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sa088kb0/) / [**Full Screen Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/sa088kb0/show/)

In some cases, you will need to ensure that the `html`/`body` element's height is set to `100%`.

For vertical alignment, set the parent element's `width`/`height` to `100%` and add `display: table`. Then for the child element, change the `display` to `table-cell` and add `vertical-align: middle`.

For horizontal centering, you could either add `text-align: center` to center the text and any other `inline` children elements. Alternatively, you could use `margin: 0 auto`, assuming the element is `block` level.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
}
.parent > .child {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<section class="parent">
    <div class="child">I'm vertically/horizontally centered!</div>
</section>
```

---

#### Absolutely positioned `50%` from the top with displacement  method:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2epdqL5g/) / [**Full Screen Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2epdqL5g/show)

This approach assumes that the text has a known height - in this instance, `18px`. Just absolutely position the element `50%` from the top, relative to the parent element. Use a negative `margin-top` value that is half of the element's known height, in this case - `-9px`.

```css
html, body, .container {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.container > p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p>I'm vertically/horizontally centered!</p>
</div>
```

---

#### The `line-height` method (Least flexible - not suggested) method:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6onex7jf/)

In some cases, the parent element will have a fixed height. For vertical centering, all you have to do is set a `line-height` value on the child element equal to the fixed height of the parent element.

Though this solution will work in some cases, it's worth noting that it won't work when there are multiple lines of text - [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/6rvdxbt9/).

```css
.parent {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    background: lightgray;
    text-align: center;
}

.parent > .child {
    line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <span class="child">I'm vertically/horizontally centered!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that works. I had already used to inline-flex on css3 so I completely forgot about how to take this aproach correctly. I really appreciate it, thank you very much.

Comment: I opened all the "Fullscreen" example above, I noticed that vertical align is always a bit too much near bottom of the screen (with resolution 1920x1080, the label is 20 pixels too low in the screen). I implemented approach #2 in my webpage and got the same problem even if the div isn't fullscreen. The problem is even worse in my webpage. (100px too low)...

Comment: You may want to add Approach 6, [using flexbox](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/) (works in IE9+, [90%+ browser market coverage](caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)): `display: flex` in the parent, and `align-self: center` in the children.

Comment: I changed a little Approach 2: http://jsfiddle.net/yeaqrh48/278/. As a result, by reducing the height of the window, the text goes beyond the scope and it becomes impossible to see. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Approach 1 worked perfectly for me. All the Flex thing (Approach 2) is very overrated, it's not that wonder they promised! And when nothing works on centering/aligning things, then the underrated and hated tables come and work brilliantly as always. Try the "sin" of using tables sometimes and see the magic!

Comment: With flexbox also `margin: auto` (without `justify-content`/`align-items`) can be used.

Comment: Approach 2 worked for me along with `writing-mode: vertical-rl` in label to add a label to a chart sideways.

Comment: @josh-crozier Just found a website with a link to your post in their css xd

Comment: approach 1 doesn't seem to work on mobile chromium browsers

Comment: The debugging tools say that `height` is an invalid property name

Answer (score 44):

If CSS3 is an option (or you have a fallback) you can use transform:

```
.center {
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%,50%);
    position: absolute;
}
```

Unlike the first approach above, you don't want to use left:50% with the negative translation because there's an overflow bug in IE9+. Utilize a positive right value and you won't see horizontal scrollbars.

Comment: I believe the transform should be `transform: translateX(50%) translateY(50%);` instead. The transform above is not syntactically correct according to the [Mozilla transform docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).

Comment: @EirikH Not sure what you were looking at, but that syntax is just fine (and says so in the docs). Most of the `transform` values that *can* take an X and Y value have a basic function to take both and specialized functions to take just one.

Answer (score 21):

Here is how to use two simple flexbox properties to center *n* divs on the two axes:

- Set the height of your container: Here the body is set to be at least 100 viewport height.
- `align-items: center;` will center the blocks vertically if flex direction is row else horizontally if flex direction is column
- `justify-content: space-around;` will distribute the free space vertically if flex direction is row else horizontally if flex direction is column around the div elements

```css
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div>foo</div>
<div>bar</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. Why min-height is 100% of viewport and not 50%?

Comment: @Lucas that's because by default the body will have the height of its contents (two lines of text in this case). If you want to center vertically in *something*, this something needs a defined height (100%, 100px, etc...). 50vh would place the elements at 25% of the height of the viewport

Answer (score 15):

The best way to center a box both vertically and horizontally, is to use two containers :

### The outher container :

- should have `display: table;`

### The inner container :

- should have `display: table-cell;`
- should have `vertical-align: middle;`
- should have `text-align: center;`

### The content box :

- should have `display: inline-block;`
- should adjust the horizontal text-alignment, unless you want text to be centered

### Demo :

```css
body {
    margin : 0;
}

.outer-container {
    display: table;
    width: 80%;
    height: 120px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.inner-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.centered-content {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    background: #fff;
    padding : 20px;
    border : 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
   <div class="inner-container">
     <div class="centered-content">
        Center this!
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/egp6tejo/)!

### Centering in the middle of the page:

To center your content in the middle of your page, add the following to your outer container :

- `position : absolute;`
- `width: 100%;`
- `height: 100%;`

Here's a demo for that :

```css
body {
    margin : 0;
}

.outer-container {
    position : absolute;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
}

.inner-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.centered-content {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    background: #fff;
    padding : 20px;
    border : 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
   <div class="inner-container">
     <div class="centered-content">
        Center this!
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8hrvjro1/)!

Answer (score 13):

### `CSS Grid: place-items`

Finally, we have [`place-items: center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items) for CSS Grid to make it easier.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="to-center"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

**Output:**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.center {
  background: #5F85DB;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="center" contenteditable>I am always super centered within my parent</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that at the time of this comment not all browsers support the `place-items` according to [canIuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=place-items).

Comment: At the time of this comment, if you are not using the browsers marked in green, https://nimb.ws/dhLU5N you are not doing it right.

Answer (score 6):

Run this code snippet and see a vertically and horizontally aligned div.

```css
html,
body,
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.mydiv {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mydiv">h & v aligned</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
    .align {
        display: flex;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        border: solid 1px black;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .align div:first-child {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: red;
        position: absolute; 
    }
    .align div {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

```html
    <div class='align'>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
```

First child will be aligned vertically and horizontally at center

Answer (score 3):

Source [Link](http://www.freakyjolly.com/best-ways-css-how-to-center-content-divs-and-images-in-center-of-screen-using-css/)

> Method 1) Display type flex
>
> ```css
> .child-element{
>     display: flex;
>     justify-content: center;
>     align-items: center;
> }
> ```
>
> Method 2) 2D Transform
>
> ```css
> .child-element {
>     top: 50%;
>     left: 50%;
>     transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
>     position: absolute;
> }
> ```

See other methods [here](http://www.freakyjolly.com/best-ways-css-how-to-center-content-divs-and-images-in-center-of-screen-using-css/)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use table:

```html
<div style="border:2px solid #8AC007; height:200px; width:200px;">
  <table style="width:100%; height:100%">
    <tr style="height:100%">
      <td style="height:100%; text-align:center">hello, multiple lines here, this is super long, and that is awesome, dude</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

to center the Div in a page <kbd>[check the fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/xKH7w/)</kbd>

```css
#vh {
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 25px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="vh">Div to be aligned vertically</div>
```

**Update**
Another option is to use flex box  <kbd>[check the fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/abbasmhd/56mc4e2u/)</kbd>

```css
.vh {
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 200px;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
.vh > div {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="vh">
    <div>Div to be aligned vertically</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is the Flex-box approach to get desired result

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Flex-box approach</title>
<style>
  .tabs{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
  }
  .f{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline; /*for vertically aligning */
    top: 9%;         /*for vertically aligning */
    position: relative; /*for vertically aligning */
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="tabs">
        <div class="f">first</div>
        <div class="f">second</div>        
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Grid css approach

```css
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
.main {
    background-color: #444;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box main"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to follow following **New** and **easy solution:**

```css
  .centered-class {
      align-items: center;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
```

```html
<div class="centered-class">
  I'm in center vertically and horizontally.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and cleanest solution for me is using the CSS3 property "transform":

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">Hello world!</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to vertically and horizontally center an element we can also use below mentioned properties.

This CSS property **aligns-items** vertically and accepts the following values:

**flex-start**: Items align to the top of the container.

**flex-end**: Items align to the bottom of the container.

**center**: Items align at the vertical center of the container.

**baseline**: Items display at the baseline of the container.

**stretch**: Items are stretched to fit the container.

This CSS property **justify-content** , which aligns items horizontally and accepts the following values:

**flex-start**: Items align to the left side of the container.

**flex-end**: Items align to the right side of the container.

**center**: Items align at the center of the container.

**space-between**: Items display with equal spacing between them.

**space-around**: Items display with equal spacing around them.

Answer (score 1):

Just make top,bottom, left and right to 0.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
<div> 
{
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
background-color: lightblue;
width: 100px;
height :100px;
padding: 25px;
top :0;
right :0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div> I am in the middle</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using CSS (your element `display:inline-grid` +  `grid-auto-flow: row;` ) Grid and Flex Box ( parent element `display:flex;`),

See below snippet

```css
#leftFrame {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#tabs {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-gap: 24px;
  justify-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

html,body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div id=leftFrame>
  <div id=tabs>
    <div>first</div>
    <div>second</div>        
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should works

```css
.center-div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-div">Center Div</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer it **without** flexbox, grid, table or `vertical-align: middle;`

You can do:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <h2 class="box__label">square</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.box__label {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translateY(50%);
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's **only about text aligning** it's simple. Just use this:

```
vertical-align: middle; /* vertical centering*/
text-align: center; /* horizontal centering*/
```

Parent styling is not needed.

**In some cases when the parent has some style properties it may affect the child, where this will not work properly**.

Answer (score 0):

- Approach 6

```css
/*Change units to "%", "px" or whatever*/

#wrapper{
  width: 50%;
  height: 70vh;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
#left{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: red;
}
#right{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: green;
}
.txt{
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="left" class="txt">Left</div>
   <div id="right" class="txt">Right</div>
</div>
```

```
    .container{ 
               width: 50%;  //Your container width here
               height: 50%; //Your container height here
               position: absolute; 
               top: 0; 
               right: 0;  
               bottom: 0; 
               left: 0; 
               margin: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of centering a div both vertically and horizontally is as follows:

```html
<div style="display: table; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
        Text Here
    </div>
</div>
```

**One More Example**:

```
.parent {
    display: table; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
}

.child {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}


<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <h4><u>SERVICE IN BANGLADESH FLEET RESERVE <br> AND <br> RE-ENGAGEMENT ORDER FOR DEFENCE SERVICE</u></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this the shortest and easiest way. However it depends on the element width and height. So feel free to adjust more the percentages on `translate(50%, 50%);`.

```css
.divContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translate(50%, 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="divContainer">I am centered</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add an answer for a duplicate willing not to use flex nor grid @ [Centering elements in CSS without using Flexbox or Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77612841/centering-elements-in-css-without-using-flexbox-or-grid/77612927)

Here is a method that was already efficient in IE5  ... updated to nowdays browser's (uses pseudo + vh unit)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  /* se me */
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%, transparent 50%);
}

body::before,
div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div {
  border: solid;
  padding: 1em;
}

body:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div>Center me via a pseudo, inline-block & vertical-align</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a related problem that people might come to this page when searching: When I want to centre a div for a "waiting.." 100px square animated gif, I use:

```css
.centreDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top:     -moz-calc(50vh - 50px);
    top:  -webkit-calc(50vh - 50px);
    top:          calc(50vh - 50px);
    left:    -moz-calc(50vw - 50px);
    left: -webkit-calc(50vw - 50px);
    left:         calc(50vw - 50px);
    z-index: 1000; /* whatever is required */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## The simplest `flexbox` approach:

The easiest way how to center a **single element** vertically and horizontally is to make it a flex item and set its margin to `auto`:

> If you apply auto margins to a flex item, that item will automatically
>   extend its specified margin to occupy the extra space in the flex
>   container...

```css
.flex-container {
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    This should be centered!
  </div>
</div>
```

This extension of margins in each direction will *push* the element exactly to the middle of its container.

Answer (score -1):

I use this CSS code:

```css
display: grid;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

The source is [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Answer (score -1):

In the case where I was trying to vertically align text content inside `button::before` and `button::after`, I was able to get it working using **`vertical-align: text-top`**.

```css
button::after {
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```